# changing order of integration and sum

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

Suppose I have a function that is represented as follows
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(x)
$$
for $- \pi \leq x \leq \pi$.
Then is it always the case that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2(x) dx 
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  a_n(x) a_m(x) dx? 
$$
I'm trying to understand the proof of Parseval's identity and it seems to do this.... but I'm confused because it involves infinite sums and I thought one can not always switch the orders around when the sum/integral has infinite range.. any clarification appreciated. thank you

Comment: Seems like I actually wrote an answer along these lines [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3918990/568204)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "... is represented as follows", you need to be more specific. I'm guessing what is meant is that $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, where the convergence is with respect to the $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ norm, i.e as $N\to\infty$,
\begin{align}
\left\|f-\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\right\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])}\to 0.
\end{align}
Even more explicitly,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^Na_n(x)\right|^2\,dx}\to 0,
\end{align}
as $N\to\infty$. The equality you wrote $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(x)$ in general does not mean a pointwise equality on $[-\pi,\pi]$. If you only have pointwise convergence, you can't swap series with integrals. Now, keeping in mind that convergence here means with respect to the $L^2$ norm, and the fact that the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $L^2$ is continuous, do you see why you can swap the series with the inner product?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I now get why I can exchange the integral and the sum, but what allows one to do $\int f(x)^2 dx = \int \sum_{n, m} a_n(x) a_m(x) dx$?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence pointwise a.e and hence equality of the integrals.